# help with binding a local service

Tags: android

I Need some help here, I have a service which I can start or stop whenever I want  and using the onStart() command to pass some extras using putExtras() from my activity

But I need some serious basic instructions on how to interact with the already created service.

Please don't refer me to another webpage which already have some implementations, just give me the needed code to interact from my UI activity to the service:

something like this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
Object ReceivedObjectFromService;

onCreate()
{

some stuff here
myMethod()

}

public class myMethod()
{
//do some stuff with the ReceivedObjectFromService
//Don't know how to call this method from the service btw
}
```

please some help, I don't understand the tutorials on how to interact service to activity or viceversa

Comment: *Please don't refer me to another webpage which already have some implementations, just give me the needed code to interact from my UI activity to the service* - That is not really the right attitude Felipeap. It sounds like you just want us to do the work for you. The way to learn these this *is* to go to various web pages that have some sample implementations you can look at.

Comment: sorry if I presented myself kind of rude, I said that because in order to understand the functionality of the service itself I had to understand other implementations in the code that I was reading, so at the end I understood the implementation and not the service itself, because there are various options to do this and looks like everyone make it their different way and I could't catch them up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interaction with already created service is no different to starting a brand new service. You just simply call `startService()` so your client code is no different.

Now, the part which is different is the service itself. In your service, `onCreate()` must start a background thread or a timer to carry on doing a work. `onStart()` will receive all `startService` cases and must in fact add the data it receives in the `Intent` to an internal list or queue and then in the timer's callback start processing from this queue.

Now you can pass any messages or data you want (even closing the service) using startService and passing data in the Intent that your service understands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, none of the examples I have seen made use of the services this way, all of them made use of a Binder Object that really made me confuse, Thank you in deep!